# Adding to a QList of a class type within a different class

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have defined the class a transaction class to specify transaction details:

```
class Transaction
{
public:
    Transaction(QString type, QDate date, int num, double price);
    QString toString();
private:
    QString m_Type;        //HOLDS THE TYPE OF TRANSACTION: Sale or Purchase
    QDate m_Date;          //date of transaction
    int m_NoOfItems;       //num of items in transaction
    double m_PricePerItem; //price per item
};
```

and a Product class to store a product's info (m_Type holds "sale" or "purchase"):

```
class Product
{
public:
Product(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc);
    void sell(int n);          //need to add sale to QList<Transaction>
    void restock(int n);
    QString getSupplierCode() const;
    void setProductCode(QString c);
    QString getProductCode() const;
    QList<Transaction> getTransactions() const;
    QString toString();
    void remvodeAll();
    bool isExpired();
private:
    QString m_Name;
    int m_NoOfItems;
    QString m_ProductCode;
    double m_SellingPrice;
    double m_SupplierPrice;
    QString m_SupplierCode;
    QList<Transaction> m_Transactions; //QList of class type Transaction
};
```

my `void Product::sell(int n)` is as follows:

```
void Product::sell(int n)
{
    if(m_NoOfItems < n)
    {
        qDebug() << "Not enough items in stock.";
    }
    else
    {
        m_NoOfItems = m_NoOfItems - n;
        m_Transactions.append(Transaction("Sale", QDate.currentDate(), n, m_SellingPrice));
    }
}
```

There is an aggregation between these classes. Now what I need to do is whenever I call `.sell()` I need to add a sale to the `QList m_Transactions` which is of class type `Transaction`, where `Transaction::m_Type = "sale"`. The only way I can think of doing this with the existing functions is to call the `Transaction` constructor and passing in the values. But obviously that won't work. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: `But obviously that won't work.` why?

Comment: I've tried `m_Transactions.append("Sale", QDate.currentDate(), n, m_SellingPrice);` Compiler complains about "Expected primary expression before "." (after QDate)

Comment: that's because you need to write `m_Transactions.append(Transaction("Sale", QDate.currentDate(), n, m_SellingPrice));`

Comment: I tried that as well and received "Expected primary expression before "(" ,between `Transaction` and `"Sale"`, in addition to the above error.

Comment: Edit your question and show your `Product::sell` method where you try to add stuff to the list.

Comment: You can't call `QDate.currentDate()` like that. It should be `QDate::currentDate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all, what you need to do is to write:

```
m_Transactions.append(Transaction("Sale", QDate::currentDate(), n, m_SellingPrice));
```

Note the `::` after `QDate`, since `currentDate()` is a static function.

I also find it a little odd to save transactions inside of products. A better design would be having a separate class that could store them.

Comment: Thank you @SingerOfTheFall, I was not aware of the static function. It now compiles error free.